# SpringBoot yml how can I run two profiles at the same time

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

In my application yml, I have two profiles which I need to both run

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: 
      awss3, @env@
  application: 
    name: CONFIG-SERVICE
```

I need awss3 to be run, in what ever the env is. Is this possible ?

Comment: have you tried spring.profiles.include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, using properties:

```
// Use your dynamic profile
spring.profiles.active=@env@
// Include your default profile
spring.profiles.include=awss3
```

yaml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: awss3
    active: 
      @env@
```

Comment: Note that the `profiles.include` directive was deprecated as of `2.4.0`. Profile groups should be preferred, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I am using 2.5.3 this is no longer supported, which is a pity as is very simple to set up

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your requirements fits Profile Groups. This approach is preferable as it allows you to visually inform the developer which *profiles* are required for which environments.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles.groups

**Example**:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      production:
      - "aws3"
      - "prodmq"
```

Then you can start the application using:

```
--spring.profiles.active=production
```

to active the production, `aws3` and `prodmq` profiles in one hit.

To clarify: The keyword `production` under group: is what you will use when you run your application as `spring.profiles.active=production`

---

Alternatively like you can simply add whatever profiles you want from the command line.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=awss3,prodmq demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: I am using Spring 2.5.3 profile groups seems quite confusing. How does Spring know which group to use The import made sense, but in groups, it does not seem to say how which  @env@ to use.

Comment: I clarified in the edited answer @Tony, good luck

Comment: Thanks for your help, I cant seem to get it working. I am running as mvn spring-boot:run. It picks up the env from the pom. And adds it to the yml using  spring:profiles:active: @activatedProperties@ in this case activatedProperties is local. But this spring:profiles:group:local: -"aws3" does not seem to work.  The param after group, that should match the activatedProperties. Just trying to get it working for local.